# How to install pacwall wallpaper in Ubuntu?

Tags: desktop-background

I'm new to Linux. I have seen a customized Linux on [unixporn](https://www.reddit.com/r/unixporn/) and really liked it. he mentioned he used [the pacwall wallpaper](https://github.com/Kharacternyk/pacwall), but when I run `sudo pacman -Syu --needed imagemagick graphviz pacman-contrib feh xorg-xdpyinfo`

I get:

```
sudo: pacman: command not found
```

Any suggestions? How to install this?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, the package manager is `apt` for Ubuntu. `pacman` is one for ArchLinux.

Comment: You haven't provided your OS/release details, which are rather important.  The site you provided won't be available via package manager (`apt` like commands) with the instructions intended for Arch users.  If you are using arch, you're asking on the wrong site, if using another OS you should provide that detail (inc. release).

Comment: pacwall [is not available on Ubunt/Debian anymore](https://github.com/Kharacternyk/pacwall/issues/40#issuecomment-655693667). Support was [dropped on v1.4.1](https://github.com/Kharacternyk/pacwall/commit/8d0bed9a8f7f94867e30fdd33c8fba67ecbc7d1f). You can try [an older release](https://github.com/Kharacternyk/pacwall/releases)